# What am I missing in my JS script which works partially correctly but fails in another case?

Tags: javascript

I have a website with some RTL contents here and there. What I'm trying to do is to add a "rtl" CSS class to all "p, div, td, th, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, li" HTML elements containing a text which starts with a RTL letter, even if the RTL text is located inside multiple levels of all "em|i|b|strong|span|a" child elements.

For example in the following cases everything works perfectly:

```
<li class="rtl"><div class="ltr"><a href="#" >
    <img src="#"></a></div><a href="#">متن</a></li>
```

and here:

```
<h2 class="rtl">متن</h2>
```

But here it fails, for example:

```
<div>
  <a href="#"><span>متن</span></a>
  <p>English description</p>
</div>
```

And here's my script:

```js
// get all P, div, td, th, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, li tags
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('p, div, td, th, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, li');

// define a function to check if a string starts with a RTL character
function startsWithRTL(str) {
  return /^[\u0600-\u06FF\u0750-\u077F\u0590-\u05FF]/.test(str);
}

// define a function to check if an element contains any direct child element with text starting with RTL characters
function hasChildWithRTL(element) {
  let hasRTL = false;
  const childNodes = element.childNodes;
  for (let i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
    const node = childNodes[i];
    if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      const nodeTag = node.tagName.toLowerCase();
      if (["em", "i", "b", "strong", "span", "a"].includes(nodeTag)) {
        const text = node.textContent.trim();
        if (startsWithRTL(text)) {
          hasRTL = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return hasRTL;
}

// loop through each element
elements.forEach((element) => {
  const text = element.textContent.trim();
  if (startsWithRTL(text) || hasChildWithRTL(element)) {
    element.classList.add('rtl');
  } else {
    element.classList.add('ltr');
  }
});
```

```css
.rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}

.ltr {
  direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#"><span>متن</span></a>
  <p>English description</p>
</div>
```

I went through the code many times and modified many things, but each time something new came up. I wonder what am I missing here which causes such a confusing issue. I'll be so grateful if you give me a hand and let me know how to fix the issue.

Comment: What doesn't work? I simply copied you code into a snippet and it runs fine...

Comment: @Salketer I appreciate your kind help! The script works well, except for the failed markup which I've mentioned. The failed markup is a div with 2 children. The parent div element should have a rtl class because its child element "a" has a rtl content starting with a rtl character. On the other hand its sibling element p should have a ltr class because it contains a content starting with a ltr character.

Comment: @Salketer I tried to fix the issue using AI, but after so many modifications, still couldn't address the issue correctly. For now I'm disappointed with AI's code writing :-))

Comment: What you describe is exactly what is happening...